# Confused about the output of this recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

I am just learning recursion and I am confused about the output of this recursive function.

```
int Run(int x)
{
    if (x > 0)
        cout << Run(x - 1) << " ";
    return x;
}
```

If I call this function with Run(5), I get the output: 0 1 2 3 4

I expected to get the output: 0 1 2 3 4 5.

I'm confused as to why 5 is not returned at the end of the output. It's the value I plugged in to the function, so after all the recursive calls are made, shouldn't the function be returning that same value I plugged in?

Comment: If you remove the conditional, you get `int Run(int x) { return x; }` which explains why 5 is returned. Adding the conditional just calls the function to get `x - 1` and print it before returning `x`.

Comment: Pretty good fodder for debugger practice.

Answer (score 1):

`Run` does return 5, but the *recursive* calls to `Run` never do, and only the return of the recursive calls are printed.

Think about it like this: you aren't printing every `x` given to `Run`; you're only printing the return of the *recursive* calls. Your first call to `Run` that makes the recursive calls returns the 5 that you're expecting to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the 0 index means that your function will be executed n times, where n = the argument integer plus 1. the thing is the `cout << Run(x - 1) << " ";` will be executed n-1 times. This is because the first function call, once it executed all the other recursive calls, will return its value of x. but since it is not returning it to a previous recursive call which would then cout that value, it is not being displayed.
try this `cout << Run(int x)` on your main function.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that *Run(n)* is a function that prints the non-negative whole numbers less than *n* and returns *n*. This means that for *Run(n)* you will get an output of *`0 1 2 ... n-1`* if *n* is positive.

What you have here:

```c++
cout << Run(x - 1) << " ";
```

is the same as

```c++
int r = Run(x - 1);
cout << r << " ";
```

That is, *Run(x-1)* will print the numbers less than *x-1* and return *x-1*. So if *x == 5* that means *Run(x-1)* printed the numbers from *0* to *x-2* and *r* was set to *4*. Then the function will print *r* and return. If you're still confused, it's also exactly the same as doing:

```c++
Run(x - 1);
cout << x-1 << " ";
```

Since we know that *Run(x-1)* will always return *x-1* we can skip storing it in a variable and print it directly. A trick when analysing recursive functions is just to assume that they work - *assume* that *Run(x-1)* successfully prints the numbers from *0* to *x-2* - the only thing left to do then is to print *x-1*.

So as you can see, the variable *x* never gets printed, only the numbers less than it. The function returns *5* but it just never prints it.

If you want it to print the non-negative whole numbers less than *or equal* to *x*, make this modification:

```c++
int Run(int x) {
  if (x >= 0) {
    cout << Run(x-1)+1 << " ";
  }
  return x;
}
```

The if statement has been changed to include *0* being printed now. *Run(x-1)* prints the numbers from *0* to *x-1* and returns *x-1*, so adding *1* to the result allows us to print *x*.